# tengo un problema al correr el comando npm install en proyectos de angular

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, typescript

Al correr el comando npm install para generar la carpeta node en cualquier proyecto angular me aparece el siguiente error. no se que podria estar pasando y por que me aparece este error al intentar correr el comando npm install.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\angular\Proyecto-Angular\platzi-store-44-auth\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\angular\Proyecto-Angular\platzi-store-44-auth\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\angular\Proyecto-Angular\platzi-store-44-auth\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.13.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\angular\Proyecto-Angular\platzi-store-44-auth\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.22.2/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.22.2/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.22.2/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz        
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.22.2 and node@16.13.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.22.2/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
```

> el package.json que incluye todas las dependencias del proyecto que quiero instalar es el siguiente

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.3",
    "firebase": "^6.5.0",
    "flexboxgrid": "^6.3.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "swiper": "^4.5.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  }
```

Comment: Tienes node instalado? La ruta bien puesta? Qué pasa si pones `node -v` en la consola de windows? "npm install" no instala "node", instala las librerías que necesita para ejecutar el proyecto en el que te encuentras.

Comment: Por favor, incluye en tu pregunta el contenido del package.json para saber qué dependencia puede estar causando líos

Comment: Tienes angular cli instalado?